# Output a 10*10 random color matrix withJPEG form in Cloud Application

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I want to output 100 JPEG Images(in 10 * 10 matrix) in Cloud Application. I came to this code:

```
ExportForm[
 Grid[Partition[ExportForm[#, "JPEG"] & /@ RandomColor[100], 
   10]], "HTML"]
```

And deploy:

```
CloudDeploy[
 ExportForm[
  Grid[Partition[ExportForm[#, "JPEG"] & /@ RandomColor[100], 10]], 
  "HTML"], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Get cloud object:

```
CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/da4b2681-15f7-4668-9cf2-31d84e4c0634"]
```

But it gives awkward text:

[image]

Question:

1. Why my code failed to output 10*10 random color matrix?
2. How to fix it?

Comment: Setup a GraphicsGrid expression that gives the desired "10*10 matrix" on the desktop. The deployed graphic should then display without having to wrap it in ExportForm HTML.

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock `CloudDeploy[ExportForm[GraphicsGrid[Partition[RandomColor[100], 10]], "HTML"],
  Permissions -> "Public"]`:https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/396e974a-24f8-4fd1-9834-1718e0959ca2, but only generate 1 image. BTW, `Grid` gives correct result in my desktop MMA.

Comment: A Grid that works on your desktop may still fail when deployed. But a GraphicsGrid that works on your desktop will probably also work in the cloud.

Comment: Instead of a simple GraphicsGrid it is also possible to deploy an HTML page with a 10 by 10 table of 100 images. Is that what you must have? Or do you want a Grid that is generated by the _Mathematica_ online application?

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock I want to deploy a application which display n*n images. Basically, I want `HTML page with a 10 by 10 table of 100 images` this.

Comment: As noted in the below answer, it's relatively easy to deploy a cloud object that displays a Grid of images. By default _Mathematica_ does this by creating an HTML Table of PNG images. Do you need to have JPEG images, or are the default PNG images OK?

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock I'm sorry and I will check your answer hours later. If there is no more further question, I will set your answer as accepted immediately.

Comment: Though the JPEG verses PNG issue may not be of your direct concern, its solution might be useful if you need more control of the cloud object's HTML output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphicsGrid cloud object:

```
CloudDeploy[Delayed[
   ExportForm[With[{dimension = 4, pixels = 32}, 
      GraphicsGrid[
         Table[Image[RandomColor[]], {dimension}, {dimension}], 
         Spacings -> 0, ImageSize -> dimension*pixels]],
      "HTML"]], 
   FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory, "RandomColorGraphicsGrid"}]]
```

[image: GraphicsGrid cloud object]

A much less efficient Grid cloud object that displays a lot of separate images:

```
CloudDeploy[Delayed[
   ExportForm[With[{dimension = 4, pixels = 32}, 
      Grid[
         Table[
            Image[Table[#, {pixels}, {pixels}] &[RandomColor[]]],
            {dimension}, {dimension}]]],
      "HTML"]], 
   FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory, "RandomColorGrid"}]]
```

[image: Grid cloud object]

In either case the Delayed gives a new random color set with each call to the cloud object.

Comment: Cool. What I want is a lot of separate images, and the second code segment works well for me. Really thanks and sorry for late reply!

Comment: I read the document about `Delayed`, but I did't catch the point why you add a `Delayed` here. Could you please explain why you add `Delayed` to your cloud application? -- Okay, I see, without Delayed it will evaluate once and every time I call remains a same picture(not random one).

Comment: Thanks for helping improve this answer!